# Varnish proxy redirects from domain.com to domain.com:8080

Tags: lighttpd, varnish

I got Varnish on port 80 before lighttpd on port 8080 as a cache. Sometimes when I go to page http://domain.com/ I'm being redirected to http://domain.com:8080. How to prevent this ?

Comment: My guess is that whatever app you have running behind lighttpd is building fully qualified redirects to http://domain.com:8080 since that's where the app believes it is running. Is it code you wrote or a package like Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both forward and reverse proxy entries to avoid this behavior.

Comment: It happens to me when I log into FlySpray.